# Why will my PL/SQL Coding not work, when trying to create 5 tables and insert 5 samples into each table?

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE TABLE Phone_Customer(
   Customer_ID  Int NOT NULL,
   First_Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   Last_Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   E_mail VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   Address VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   First_Name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
   City VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
   State CHAR (2) NOT NULL,
   Age INT NOT NULL,
   Zip INT NOT NULL,
   Phone VarChar(30)   
   CONSTRAINT  Phone_Customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone_Order(
   Order_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Customer_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Item_ID   INT NOT NULL,
   Shipping_Method_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Shipping_Status_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Quantity INT NOT NULL,
   Shipping_Date DATE,
   Total_Due DECIMAL(18,2)
   Credit_Card_Number Char(16)
   Credit_Card_Expiration Varchar2(5)

   CONSTRAINT Phone_Order_pk PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Customer_Id FOREIGN KEY(Customer_Id)
    References Customer(Customer_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Item_ID FOREIGN KEY(Item_ID)
        References Item(Item_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Shipping_Method_ID FOREIGN KEY(Shipping_Method_Id) References Shipping Method(Shipping_Method_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Shipping_Status_ID FOREIGN KEY(Shiping_Status_ID)
    References Shipping Status(Shipping_Status_ID)

);

CREATE TABLE Phone_Item(
   Item_ID   INT NOT NULL,
   Brand VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   Model VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   E_mail VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   Operating_System VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   Price DECIMAL(18,2),
   Screen_Size DECIMAL(4,2),
   Camera_Resolution VARCHAR2(10),
   Network VARCHAR2(4),
   RAM INT NOT NULL,
   storage INT NOT NULL,
   Talk_Time INT NOT NULL,
   COLOR VARCHAR2(16),
   CONSTRAINT Phone_Item_pk PRIMARY_KEY(Item_ID)

);

CREATE TABLE Phone_Shipping_Method(

Shipping_Method_ID INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Phone_Shipping_Method_pk PRIMARY_KEY(Shipping_Method_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone_Shipping_Status(

Shipping_Status_ID INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Reset_Shipping_Date DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Phone_Shipping_Status_pk PRIMARY_KEY(Shipping_Method_ID)
);



INSERT ALL
INTO Phone_Shipping_Status(Shipping_Status_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)VALUES(5029508, 'James',To_Date( '010988', 'MMDDYY'))

INTO Phone_Shipping_Status(Shipping_Status_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(450767, 'James Walker',TO_DATE( '050978', 'MMDDYY'))


INTO Phone_Shipping_Status(Shipping_Status_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(3, 'Jim Curack',TO_DATE( '070989', 'MMDDYY'))


 INTO Phone_Shipping_Status(Shipping_Status_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(8, 'Jaime Heimberger',TO_DATE( '070989', 'MMDDYY'))

INTO Phone_Shipping_Status(Shipping_Status_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(9, 'Dwayne Johnson',TO_DATE( '100999', 'MMDDYY'))

SELECT * FROM dual;



INSERT ALL
INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(50295656, 'Ricky Bobby',TO_DATE( '010308', 'MMDDYY'))


INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(4507655, 'Bobby Heenan',TO_DATE( '050998', 'MMDDYY'))


INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(3747547, 'Jim-long Johnson',TO_DATE( '070969', 'MMDDYY'))


INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(8432525, 'J Joshua johnson',TO_DATE( '070909', 'MMDDYY'))


INTO Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_Id,Name, Reset_Shipping_Date)
VALUES(943252, 'Dusty Rhodes',TO_DATE( '100999', 'MMDDYY'))
SELECT * FROM dual;



INSERT ALL
INTO Phone_Customer(Customer_Id,First_Name, Last_Name, E_mail, Address,  City, State ,  Age , Zip , Phone )
VALUES(508, 'James','Buchannen','j@gmail.com','999 james road','Los     Angeles','CA',67,54666,'123456789')

INTO Phone_Customer(Customer_Id,First_Name, Last_Name, E_mail, Address,  City, State ,  Age , Zip , Phone )
VALUES(508534, 'Jasmine','Buchannen','jasmine21@gmail.com','99056 jumanji road','RainForest,'CA',67,54666,'126956789')

INTO Phone_Customer(Customer_Id,First_Name, Last_Name, E_mail, Address,  City, State ,  Age , Zip , Phone )
VALUES(5432508, 'Clyde','Buchannen','ClydeB57@yahoo.com','65465 james ave','Los     Angeles','CA',67,54667,'125436789')

INTO Phone_Customer(Customer_Id,First_Name, Last_Name, E_mail, Address,  City, State ,  Age , Zip , Phone )
VALUES(7657508, 'Jimmy','Buchannen','jimmyB@gmail.com','4569 roady road','Los   Angeles','CA',67,54669,'165432789')

INTO Phone_Customer(Customer_Id,First_Name, Last_Name, E_mail, Address,  City, State ,  Age , Zip , Phone )
VALUES(576708, 'Bonnie','Buchannen','Bonniej_buch@aol.com','11999 teeal road','Los  Angeles','CA',67,54676,'176543289')
SELECT * FROM dual;




INSERT ALL
INTO Phone_Order(Order_Id,Customer_Id, Item_Id, Shipping_Method_Id,     Shipping_Status_Id, Quantity, Shipping_date, Total_Due, Credit_Card_Number.     Credit_Card_Expiration)
Values( 432532,5325234,4565,34553,675675,5, To_Date( '100999', 'MMDDYY'), 56.98,'3456456453334444,'05/17')

INTO Phone_Order(Order_Id,Customer_Id, Item_Id, Shipping_Method_Id,     Shipping_Status_Id, Quantity, Shipping_date, Total_Due, Credit_Card_Number.     Credit_Card_Expiration)
Values( 45435432,5254354354,47675,3765766553,675757555,5, To_Date( '100100', 'MMDDYY'), 96.99,'3456456111134444,'05/18')


INTO Phone_Order(Order_Id,Customer_Id, Item_Id, Shipping_Method_Id,     Shipping_Status_Id, Quantity, Shipping_date, Total_Due, Credit_Card_Number,     Credit_Card_Expiration)
Values( 4542,52554,475,766553,7555,1, To_Date( '111111', 'MMDDYY'), 96.99,'345645611342133333,'05/11')

INTO Phone_Order(Order_Id,Customer_Id, Item_Id, Shipping_Method_Id,     Shipping_Status_Id, Quantity, Shipping_date, Total_Due, Credit_Card_Number,     Credit_Card_Expiration)
Values( 42,554,45,765,75,100, To_Date( '121212', 'MMDDYY'), 76.99,'3456451234566786678,'05/16')

INTO Phone_Order(Order_Id,Customer_Id, Item_Id, Shipping_Method_Id,     Shipping_Status_Id, Quantity, Shipping_date, Total_Due, Credit_Card_Number,     Credit_Card_Expiration)
Values( 8778872,55878784,4598898,769895,765665,1, To_Date( '122317', 'MMDDYY'), 50.99,'34564512345555578,'05/115')
Select * From dual;

INSERT ALL
INTO Phone_Item(Item_Id, Brand, Model, Price, Operating_System, Screen_Size, Camera_Resolution,Network,RAM,Storage,Talk_Time,Color)
Values(123344, 'samsung','galaxy',56.78,'Android',13.7,'1200x1200','4g'56,120,178,'black')

INTO Phone_Item(Item_Id, Brand, Model, Price, Operating_System, Screen_Size, Camera_Resolution,Network,RAM,Storage,Talk_Time,Color)
Values(123134, 'samsung','galaxy',567.78,'Android',13,'120x700','4g',100,100,5178,'green')

INTO Phone_Item(Item_Id, Brand, Model, Price, Operating_System, Screen_Size, Camera_Resolution,Network,RAM,Storage,Talk_Time,Color)
Values(123321, 'samsung','galaxy',656.78,'Android',17,'100x100','4g',90,10,1678,'purple')

INTO Phone_Item(Item_Id, Brand, Model, Price, Operating_System, Screen_Size, Camera_Resolution,Network,RAM,Storage,Talk_Time,Color)
Values(12333, 'samsung','galaxy',156.78,'Android',3,'200x200','4g',90,20,8178,'brown')

INTO Phone_Item(Item_Id, Brand, Model, Price, Operating_System, Screen_Size, Camera_Resolution,Network,RAM,Storage,Talk_Time,Color)
Values(1233, 'samsung','galaxy',356.78,'Android',7,'1200x1200','4g',56,1200,1788,'blue')
Select * from dual;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not work"? Do you get an error? Or unexpected results? The more details you give us, the more easily we can help you!

Comment: Let's do each table at a time. I got the first table to work now. For the Phone_Order table, I receive the following error: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: This forum is not for asking debugging help. Please be specific in your question and errors

Comment: missing commas after several of the lines in Phone_Order, comma instead of period in decimals all over as well. PL/SQL uses the US form of decimals. 0.0 not 0,0. Also clearly mismatched apostrophes as indicated by the value coloration errors (Rainforest)

Answer (score 1):

duplicate column name, missing commas (every column and constraint definition should be separated by a comma), `PRIMARY KEY` should not have underline: "PRIMARY_KEY" is incorrect. Phone_Shipping_Status table has invalid column name for it's Primary Key and I think it should be Shipping_Status_ID. a typo in Shiping_Status_ID and it should be Shipping_Status_ID, Foreign Keys for Phone_customer and Phone_item table is typed Customer and Item...
And the most important thing is the order of Tables definition according to relations between them that I re-arranged the order.
I don't think the inserts have important issue, really I didn't check them.
It's your correct DDL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Phone_Customer(
   Customer_ID  Int NOT NULL,
   First_Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   Last_Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   E_mail VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   Address VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   City VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
   State CHAR (2) NOT NULL,
   Age INT NOT NULL,
   Zip INT NOT NULL,
   Phone VarChar(30),
   CONSTRAINT  Phone_Customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Phone_Item(
   Item_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Brand VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   Model VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   E_mail VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   Operating_System VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
   Price DECIMAL(18,2),
   Screen_Size DECIMAL(4,2),
   Camera_Resolution VARCHAR2(10),
   Network VARCHAR2(4),
   RAM INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Storage INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Talk_Time INTEGER NOT NULL,
   COLOR VARCHAR2(16),
   CONSTRAINT Phone_Item_pk PRIMARY KEY (Item_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Phone_Shipping_Method(
Shipping_Method_ID INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Phone_Shipping_Method_pk PRIMARY KEY (Shipping_Method_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone_Shipping_Status(
   Shipping_Status_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   Reset_Shipping_Date DATE NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Phone_Shipping_Status_pk PRIMARY KEY(Shipping_Status_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone_Order(
   Order_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Customer_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Item_ID   INT NOT NULL,
   Shipping_Method_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Shipping_Status_ID INT NOT NULL,
   Quantity INT NOT NULL,
   Shipping_Date DATE,
   Total_Due DECIMAL(18,2),
   Credit_Card_Number Char(16),
   Credit_Card_Expiration Varchar2(5),
   CONSTRAINT Phone_Order_pk PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Customer_Id FOREIGN KEY(Customer_Id) 
     References Phone_Customer(Customer_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Item_ID FOREIGN KEY(Item_ID)
     References Phone_Item(Item_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Shipping_Method_ID FOREIGN KEY(Shipping_Method_Id)
     References Phone_Shipping_Method(Shipping_Method_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Shipping_Status_ID FOREIGN KEY(Shipping_Status_ID)
     References Phone_Shipping_Status(Shipping_Status_ID)
);
```